# Convert human readable time into EPOCH using shell script

Tags: shell, date, epoch

I have a human readable time as

```
08-18-2016 09:18:25
```

I want it to be converted into epoch time using shell script.

I tried with `date "+%s"` but I am getting the error

> date: invalid date `08-18-2016 09:32:42'

Comment: epoch meaning seconds since 1/1/1970?

Comment: output should be '1471511905'

Comment: do you know about `date -d"... your date ..." "+%s"`?

Comment: I have tried that, but did not worked.
Getting error : date: invalid date `08-18-2016 09:32:42'

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to convert a datetime into epoch is to use:

```
date "+%s"                    # for this moment's date
date -d" some date" "+%s"     # for a specific date
```

However, in this case the format is not valid:

```
$ date -d"08 18 2016 09:18:25" "+%s"
date: invalid date ‘08 18 2016 09:18:25’
```

You need, then, to massage the string a bit before passing it to `date -d`.

This converts the two first spaces into slashes:

```
$ sed 's# #/#;s# #/#' <<< "08 18 2016 09:18:25"
08/18/2016 09:18:25
```

So this works:

```
$ date -d"$(sed 's# #/#;s# #/#' <<< "08 18 2016 09:18:25")" "+%s"
1471504705
```

Or using variables:

```
$ nice_date=$(sed 's# #/#;s# #/#' <<< "08 18 2016 09:18:25")
$ date -d"$nice_date" "+%s"
1471504705
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation fedorqui.
But 1471511905 is the epoch time for  08 18 2016 09:18:25, not 1471504705.

Comment: @MohitRane well, this must be related to your locale. Just run it in your machine and see what is the output.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks for the explanation fedorqui. But 1471511905 is the epoch time
>   for 08 18 2016 09:18:25, not 1471504705. – Mohit Rane

`date -u …` will print *Coordinated Universal Time*.